# C# process RedirectStandardOutput not redirecting

Tags: c#, perl, process, redirectstandardoutput

I want to redirect standardoutput of a `Process` in a `richTextBox`. Here is my process configuration,

```
        string command = "/K perl C:\\Server.pl ";

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        Process proc = new Process();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = command;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, ea) => this.richTextBox1.AppendText(ea.Data);
        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Here is my `Server.pl` file

```
        print "Server1 \n";

        while(1)
        {
            print "Server \n";
            sleep 1;
        }
```

But when I run the program the cmd.exe is just black and nothing printed in richTextBox. but when I change the

```
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
```

I have this out put in my cmd.exe:

```
        Server1
        Server
        Server
        Server
        ...
```

How I can work around this issue ?

Comment: I know that is possible to run `perl.exe` instead of `cmd.exe`, but based on some reasons I need to make this solution work with cmd.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be as simple as disabling output buffering in your perl script. This is done using the `$|` special variable (see [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)).

```
$| = 1;
print "Server1 \n";
...
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was that simple. But what I don't understand is why by (startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;) perl doesn't do output buffering anymore?!